# Azure Devops - Nested Variables At Runtime

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a set of databases that I am trying to work with in Azure Devops.
I have a variable group that has various pieces of information for each database.
The variables follow a convention of .
CoreUserName, CoreIPAddress
TestUserName, TestIPAddress
FooUserName, FooIPAddress

The databases come into the template via parameterized array of strings that I am doing a foreach over. What I need is a way to resolve the value of the variables for the current item in the array.

Say the array is passed in like this:

`dbPackages: ['Core','Test']`

I need a way to take Core and append UserName (to CoreUserName) and then resolve the value of the CoreUserName variable.

I know that nested parameters "are not supported" but I am wondering if something like this can be accomplished with setting variables in a bash or powershell script? I just haven't figured out the proper syntax.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's two possible syntaxes. I'm assuming you're defining `dbStages` as a parameter and doing foreach loop in the pipeline....

#### As Environment Variables

All pipeline variables are available at runtime as environment variables, so it's possible to access them in several different ways programmatically. Here I'm passing Core/Test/Foo as an `env` value and then accessing it as an environment variable.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: dbStages
  type: object
  default:
  - Core
  - Test
  - Foo

variables:
- group: myVariableGroup

steps:
- ${{ each dbPrefix in parameters.dbStages }}:
  - task:PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        
        $prefix = $env:prefix
        $varUserName  = $prefix + "UserName"

        # access through $env
        $UserName = $env:$varUserName

        # access through Env: provider
        $UserName = Get-Item Env:$varUserName

        # access through .NET
        $UserName = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($varUserName)

      env:
        prefix: ${{ dbPrefix }}
```

You could go one step further, and de-reference `CoreUserName` to `UserName` by using the available [Logging Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell). Subsequent tasks would be able to use the `$(UserName)` variable...

```
$UserName = $env:$( $prefix + "UserName" )
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=UserName]$UserName"
```

#### Through Macro Syntax

The second option is to access the variables through the `$()` macro syntax. It's important to realize that **parameters are resolved** when the pipeline is *compiled* and **variables are evaluated** at *runtime*.

We can leverage compile time parameters to construct the macro syntax with the variable name you want to evaluate at runtime:

```yaml
- ${{ each dbPrefix in parameters.dbStages }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        
         # resolves into "$(CoreUserName)" at compile time
         # by is evaluated as "<value-of-CoreUserName>" at runtime
         $userName = "$(${{ dbPrefix }}UserName)"
```

Comment: The macro syntax you provided ended up being the cleanest for me. 
"$(${{ dbPrefix }}UserName)"
The env variable approaches did not seem to work as expected - probably my syntax.